# Make a change that is ignored by future merges

Tags: git, branching

I have a git repository, and I'd like to make a "debug" branch.

In the "debug" branch, I'd like to add a line:

```
debug = true;
```

But I want to make sure that any merges back to master ignore that change. Is there any way to set that up in way that doesn't require me to manually handle all future merges?

Comment: Don't put it in the versioned code. Put it in a config file which gets ignored by git. A `debug` flag shouldn't be a property of a branch in the first place.

Comment: Do you mean don't commit it? Then I'm in a situation where I have to step on eggshells every commit to avoid accidentally committing it.

Comment: Create a config file (for example called `localconfig`) which you include in your `.gitignore` file so you can't accidentally commit it. Don't mix local configuration with code.

Comment: That's why I said that you should isolate local configuration into a separate config file. All machine specific configuration should be put in that file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create the branch (let's call it 'debug'), make the change and commit to that branch.

```
git checkout -b debug
vim config # add debug = true
git commit config -m "Turn on debug mode"
```

Then check out master and start the merge process

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff --no-commit debug
```

This will tell git to merge, create an actual merge commit instead of fast-forwarding, and stage the commit but not actually commit it yet. Then go into the file and remove the line that you added on the branch and finally commit.

```
vim config # remove debug=true
git commit
```

If you run `gitk master debug`, you should see that debug has been merged into master, but master doesn't have the `debug=true` change. From now on, when you merge the debug branch into master, git will not try to reincorporate the `debug=true` because that was already "merged".

As other commenters have stated, config files like this shouldn't be checked into version control. The common way to avoid this is to have the application check for a local config file that is either outside the source directory or in a file that is in .gitignore. But if that's not possible, the above instructions will work.